# How to center background image to coordinates?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am wondering what is the best way to center background image to wanted point on the image.

I have a 2000x1000px map and I have chosen point, which is defined by percentage values. Let's say left: 75% top: 50%.

Then I want to display this point in mobile device. This image will be a DIV background so that the image is cropped to fit the DIV and this given point is right in the center of the DIV.

Also I would like to show as much as possible. Point at 95% 95% wouldn't be in the center, but instead background-position would be 100% 100%.

Comment: See this reference [Background|Codrops Reference](http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/background/)

Comment: what you've done so far?